# Cookie won't set expiration

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

I'm setting this cookie in Google Tag Manager but when I inspect the cookie with my Chrome plugin it's showing as expired as soon as it was set.  I want it to be set for 7 days.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  I've been looking at other examples online and I can't see what I'm missing!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">document.cookie = "retailview=true;expires=7*24*60*60*1000;domain=visioncritical.com;path=/;";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me work it out.  Here is the solution:

```
var a = new Date();
a = new Date(a.getTime() +7*24*60*60*1000);
document.cookie = "retailview=true;expires="+a.toGMTString()+";domain=visioncritical.com;path=/";
```